# Downloading Pre-trained model from Github

Tags: github, download, repository

i found this repository https://github.com/forever208/yolov5_train_on_UAVDT on Github. But I have no idea what this code is doing!

i need the weights and cfg file of the trained model on UAVDT from this repository to use it for my code.

somebody please help! and very much thankyou for your valuable help in advance

I tried running this code but i have no idea why i am getting so many error. i am stuck. instead of clearing the error end of the day i only need the weights and cfg file